# Wider display width for ipython/jupyter notebooks from within github

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

I use the following for wider display in a native IPython / Jupyter notebook:

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

Here is the terse documentation on this topic from GitHub:  https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-jupyter-notebook-files-on-github/

[image]

However that is not respected within GitHub rendering.  Is there any directive that works specifically for GitHub?

Comment: What do you mean by "GitHub rendering"? Are you trying to host using GitHub Pages? Are you rendering some content in an README?

Comment: Github does display the notebooks: but it is restricting the width of the cells much more than in the original ones.

Comment: GitHub displays them _how_? There are different processes in place depending on whether this is in a wiki, a README, a GitHub Pages site, etc.

Comment: Have you ever looked at an `.ipynb` on github?   In any case here is an example.  https://github.com/hgbrian/ipynb_experiments/blob/master/PCA_in_TensorFlow.ipynb

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for clarifying. I don't believe there is any way to do what you want. GitHub doesn't like any user-generated content to change the way its own UI works. An example would be rendered README files, where [HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, inline-styles, and `class` or `id` attributes](https://github.com/github/markup/tree/master#github-markup). `.ipynb` files aren't listed there, but I bet they're given similar treatment.